# Rust Racer autocomplete problem in Cygwin

Tags: company-mode, rust

I'm trying to set up racer mode for Rust language autocomletion, but when press 'tab' key got messages like this:

> Company: An error occurred in auto-begin
> Company: backend company-capf error "/cygdrive/d/Soft/Cygwin64/home/racer/target/release/racer exited with status 1" with args (candidates B)
> Company: An error occurred in auto-begin
> Company: backend company-capf error "/cygdrive/d/Soft/Cygwin64/home/racer/target/release/racer exited with status 1" with args (candidates B)
> Company: An error occurred in auto-begin
> Company: backend company-capf error "/cygdrive/d/Soft/Cygwin64/home/racer/target/release/racer exited with status 1" with args (candidates B)

Here is my .emacs:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)


(setq company-tooltip-align-annotations t)

(setq racer-cmd "/cygdrive/d/Soft/Cygwin64/home/racer/target/release/racer")
(setq racer-rust-src-path "/home/rust/src/")

(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook #'racer-mode)
(add-hook 'racer-mode-hook #'eldoc-mode)

(add-hook 'racer-mode-hook #'company-mode)

(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") #'company-indent-or-complete-common) ;

(defun rust-save-compile-and-run ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)

  (if (locate-dominating-file (buffer-file-name) "Cargo.toml")

      (compile "cargo run")

    (compile
     (format "rustc %s & %s"
         (buffer-file-name)
         (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name))))))

(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (define-key rust-mode-map (kbd "<f5>") 'rust-save-compile-and-run)))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

### UPDATE:

So, when i try to call racer from emacs shell, i got following message:

```
racer can't find the directory pointed to by the RUST_SRC_PATH variable "/cygdrive/c/src/rust/tasks/src/C:\Program Files\Rust stable 1.5\rustc-1.5.0\src". Try using an absolute fully qualified path and make sure it points to the src directory of a rust checkout - e.g. "/home/foouser/src/rust/src".
```

But i don't know how to fix this. By the way, i'm working in Cygwin.

Now, i got following error:

```
eldoc error: (error /cygdrive/d/Soft/Cygwin64/home/racer/target/release/racer exited with status 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install rust source code and set the RUST_SRC_PATH environment variable. It's the point 4 in "Install from sources" in the racer readme https://github.com/phildawes/racer.

Comment: Already done, but it still does not works.